# Angular2 : The responses to HTTP get requests are being cached in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, angular, caching, get, httprequest

The responses to most HTTP get requests are being cached in IE Edge. 
It doesn't happen in other browsers as far as I know.
I fixed that on older versions, but How can I do it on Angular2?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common fix is to add a random query parameter value to the request URL.
You can create a custom `Http` implementation that does that for each request.

```ts
@Injectable() 
class NoCacheHttp extends Http {
  constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(_backend, _defaultOptions);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable<Response> {
    let newUrl = /* add some random or incrementing number query parameter to URL */
    return super.get(newUrl, options);
  }

  post(...)
  ...
}
```

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  export: [HttpModule],
  providers: [{provide: Http, useClass: NoCacheHttp}]
})
export class NoCacheHttpModule {}
```

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, NoCacheHttpModule],
  declarations: [AppModule],
  bootstrap: [AppModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I didnt get where should I put these @NgModule s . should the second one be in app.module? and the first one in separate module? Also could you please explain providers: [{Http, useClass: NoCacheHttp}] ?

Comment: it seems correct solution. I just have one issue , No provider for ConnectionBackend! in AppComponent

Comment: That's weird. If you have `HttpModule` imported, `ConnectionBackend` should be available. I'll try it myself..

Comment: Sorry, I had a few mistakes in my code. This is working https://plnkr.co/edit/N3BUIVt5r3hVVZpK0tTY?p=preview. I had to add the `ConnectionBackend` provider explicitely. I don't know why this is necessary. Perhaps something related to the order how providers are added to the root scope.

Comment: Glad to hear :)