# Angular2: Subscribe to all HTTP requests

Tags: angular

I'm building a webapp using Angular2.

Is it possible to execute a function each time Angular2 makes a HTTP request?

This will be used for checking if the JWT token needs to be refreshed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom `Http` class that provides an observable that components or other services can subscribe to and that emits an event every time a request is made

```ts
@Injectable() 
class NotifyingHttp extends Http {
  requestSent:Subject = new Subject();
  requestCompleted:Subject = new Subject();
  constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(_backend, _defaultOptions);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable<Response> {
    this.requestSent.next(url);
    return super.get(newUrl, options)
    .finally(response => this.requestCompleted.next(url));
  }

  post(...)
  ...
}
```

Each method needs to be overridden this way (get, post, ...)

You can create a shared module that is then activated by adding it to imports of `AppModule`:

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  export: [HttpModule],
  providers: [
   {provide: ConnectionBackend: useClass XhrBackend},
   {provide: Http, useClass: NotifyingHttp}]
})
export class NotifyingHttpModule {}
```

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, NotifyingHttpModule],
  declarations: [AppModule],
  bootstrap: [AppModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See also [Angular2 : The responses to HTTP get requests are being cached in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988263/angular2-the-responses-to-http-get-requests-are-being-cached-in-ie/40990199#40990199)

Comment: You need to use a factory. Extending Http Still causes the Http constructor to be called by Angular, instead of the custom class constructor ([related to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40295956/2587435)). So you need to use a factory and create it yourself. And since ConnectionBackend is an interface (no provider for that token), you need to use XHRBackend for the factory.

Comment: That might explain why I hadd to add a provider `{provide: ConnectionBackend: useClass XhrBackend}`, but that should do (according to a test in a plunker I recently made)